# How do you save an image from webpage to server?

Tags: php, html

I have an image id='canvasImg' and I can not figure out how to take this image and save it to the server.

I tried saving the contents to a form and then putting the contents in a png file after decode but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a simple file form upload

**HTML**

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP (upload_file.php)**

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
 echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
 "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
```